# If statement not working - have to hit enter twice

Tags: python, if-statement

This is a snippet of a code I am working on but I am really stuck on why it isn't working.

The if statement (yes) works perfect but the elif and the else do not throw errors or register anything when I type anything other than yes.

```
while current_room == 'Bathroom':
    if 'Lavender Oil,' not in inventory:
        print('Wow, this bathroom has so many bottles of stuff!')
        print('Do you want to investigate the shelf of bottles?')
        if input().strip().lower() == 'yes':
            print('yes')
        elif input().strip().lower() == 'no':
            print('no')
        else:
            print('else')
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing a little bit based on your description, but I think the issue is that this:

```
if input().strip().lower() == 'yes':
    print('yes')
elif input().strip().lower() == 'no':
    print('no')
```

is different than

```
cmd = input.strip().lower()
if cmd == 'yes':
    print('yes')
elif cmd == 'no':
    print('no')
```

Specifically, in the code you tried, it asks for user input twice, once in the original `if` clause, and a second time in the `elif` clause. This means the thing you're comparing against isn't stable. The solution is to store the user response, and *then* compare it to available options.

Comment: Sorry, I know it's super vague.  I am putting the bones together for a text-based game and I am just doing the basic no details first.  I changed it to your recommendation and it works...thank you so much!

Comment: @KennedyStrand The detail I was looking for was more, 'This is the input I tried and this is the output I got when I expected this other output.' I would expect, for instance, for the game to wait at the elif statement for your second input - but you didn't describe if it did that. Regardless, glad we could help - don't forget to accept answers, it helps you get more and better results in the future!